# Implicit typescript key map use

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

Is it possible to implicitly state the possible options (based on the `key`) for the `name` property in the example below:

```js
type TypeMap = {
  A: 1 | 2 | 3;
  B: 4 | 5 | 6;
};

type InnerType<TKey extends keyof TypeMap> = {
  key: TKey;
  name: TypeMap[TKey];
  // + other properties;
};

type OuterType = {
  x: InnerType; // Should be agnostic at this point
  y: InnerType; // but typescript requires a generic definition
};

const foo: OuterType = {
  x: { key: "A", name: 2 },
  y: { key: "B", name: 4 },
};
```

The closest I can come up with would be something like the following, (but I would rather not have to change the format of the respective types):

```js
type TypeMap = {
  A: 1 | 2 | 3;
  B: 4 | 5 | 6;
};

type InnerType = {
  data: Partial<{ [key in keyof TypeMap]: TypeMap[key] }>;
  // + other properties
};

type OuterType = {
  x: InnerType;
  y: InnerType;
};

const foo: OuterType = {
  x: { data: { A: 2 } }, // not blocking me from using `{}` or `{ A: 2, B: 4 }` on the same object
  y: { data: { B: 4 } },
};
```

Another approach would be the following (but does not limit based on the key):

```js
type TypeMap = {
  A: 1 | 2 | 3;
  B: 4 | 5 | 6;
};

type InnerType = {
  key: keyof TypeMap;
  name: TypeMap[keyof TypeMap];
  // + other properties;
};

type OuterType = {
  x: InnerType;
  y: InnerType;
};

const foo: OuterType = {
  x: { key: "A", name: 2 }, // allows me to use `{ key: "A", name 4 }`
  y: { key: "B", name: 4 },
};
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N78VPm) using a distributive object type meet your needs? `InnerType` without a generic type argument needs to be a union.  If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it does, thank you! However I don't understand why the generic is required, it seems to work without it just fine, or am I missing something? [changed example](https://tsplay.dev/Nroy5m)

Comment: It isn’t *required* to have it generic… you’re the one who made it generic so I preserved that for you. A plain union is also fine if you don’t want to use generics. I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `InnerType` is a single object type whose properties are [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), which allows mixing of `key` and `name` in a way you don't want. You really want `InnerType` to itself be a union of object types, like this:

```
type InnerType = {
    key: "A";
    name: 1 | 2 | 3;
} | {
    key: "B";
    name: 4 | 5 | 6;
}
```

That gives you the behavior you want:

```
const foo: OuterType = {
    x: { key: "A", name: 1 },
    y: { key: "B", name: 5 }
};

const badFoo: OuterType = {
    x: { key: "A", name: 4 }, // error! 
    // Type '{ key: "A"; name: 4; }' is not assignable to type 'InnerType'.
    // Type '4' is not assignable to type '1 | 2 | 3'.
    y: { key: "A", name: 2 }
}
```

---

You can even write `InnerType` in terms of `TypeMap` so that it will automatically update if `TypeMap` is updated:

```
type InnerType = { [K in keyof TypeMap]:
    { key: K, name: TypeMap[K] }
}[keyof TypeMap]
```

This `InnerType` is a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). It works by [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the keys `K` of `TypeMap`, computing the desired object type for each key `K`, and then [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the mapped type with `keyof TypeMap`, resulting in the desired union.

---

If for some reason you want to keep `InnerType` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) so that `InnerType<K>` corresponds to a particular `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof TypeMap`, you can do it:

```
type InnerType<K extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> =
    { [P in K]:
        { key: P, name: TypeMap[P] }
    }[K]

type InnerTypeA = InnerType<"A">
/* type InnerTypeA = {
  key: "A";
  name: 1 | 2 | 3;
} */

type InnerTypeB = InnerType<"B">
/* type InnerTypeB = {
  key: "B";
  name: 4 | 5 | 6;
} */
```

And note that `K` [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `keyof TypeMap`, so that `InnerType` without a generic type argument is equivalent to the full union:

```
type InnerTypeBoth = InnerType
/* type InnerTypeBoth = {
  key: "A";
  name: 1 | 2 | 3;
} | {
  key: "B";
  name: 4 | 5 | 6;
} */
```

So you can get both generic-like and union-like behavior depending on your needs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8BQBIAggFxQCMUAPlAEwVQDMA3HgELEAstArLQGxMC+TbKEhQAkgDsJEAE5xRGTFADaAaSgBLCVADWEEAHsAZrHjIwAXUJ4lekMVUAaKBKQBbCMXmIUai1H5sfmU7Y1NIcwtsaIB6ACooEWhJaTl4dCw8O2IAInwcplxXD2IyShpKRiDaHFxsqBzmArxizygOSm5KPmq4mOikqAB5AFdgWW8M2oAPYhSJ+AYoGJioAGUACwMRgBsAEygAI2gkAHMJAwBnYA0AYygkYESNjUuoMAMtYDx7cSkFyBLFZHMaJeCXW4yDRgJ4yCAARxGGjhbyQUFOEFSdygewgRi0GhuBgkQSEt2J1ygRgMBmIo3GaQUmVwsywun0uXyzlapQCjh+xFsHIaTW57ja3H4-ME0XJEkphyQewAYjS6WMAdBFHhWULfnkcmKSu0+ctVrIZAYZABCXB4YGTADkes5BRc4vYS34js0bwuTyQl0uGnOSEOO2gwAMYNEjvmjIgAB5QiZvOYAHyOgB09tW4QgbzCYEtkBkoCgjtaPqQcM0EnJbjAjw04YgWag+YrbB9rxcBgDQZDrlbiWjg0dZWotDo2YFbPqBqNbRogUC2Falybt2gAA1mYN495E+oINNxhI9m8U-nzBlr2mUOn0HhcEplAAFOtQVRWF+v9m-O+S5eGYvjvv4gS4LgwQ-tEuAHv8Cb4Bkh7wImBrpvaCQIak3jIdquAdgu+SFB2PKkLQFT0IU-BQH0cE4ZqzAoYhR6NDkmG4PEMbJKx8DMQRRHCuxpHusaHRQF0UA9NBdH9HgjEJsw-YbCxuHwFhPF-OpkDKcAqmCQBrqieRk5UVUsmULUQn6k0JkeianS8DRcnRGuQA)

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented the plain "distributive object type" approach since I also want to use the `TypeMap` type for further declarations. Also thank you for supplying a description and references for "distributive object type" since it's the first time I'm hearing of the term and I intend to look further into it.